# Using the same Elastic Index from 2 different applications with different package structures to store the data(HibernateSearch + Elastic)

Tags: elasticsearch, hibernate-search

We have Elastic 5.6.10 an HibernateSearch ORM 5.11.4.Final installed on one of our application server and now we are planning to use the same Elastic instance and its indexes through one of our micro service(spring boot, but using the same HibernateSearch and Elastic versions). Reason for this being, we are planning to store data from both these application to a single index(as they would be same data), so that we can search on each others data from both the application.

The issue we are facing is with qualified names of the entities. As on the first application the Entity is for example under com.abc.data.to.FirstAppClassTO and the structure on the microservice is like com.abc.service.model.MicroserviceClassTO(or any other package type). Now the issue is we are creating the initial indexes from our first application. But now if we try to make the com.abc.service.model.MicroserviceClassTO as indexed it will create a new one or if we provide the same index name than it will override the existing one(which was created from the first application).

Is there any way in hibernate search or Elastic Search we can implement this the way we intend to.

**First Application TO and Elastic Schema:**

```
 @Entity
    @Indexed(index="master_index")
    public class UserTO{
```

Schema on Elastic:

```
{
  "master_client_index" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "com.abc.pt.svc.data.to.UserTO" : {
```

**Microservice TO and Schema:**

```
@Entity
@Indexed(index = "master_index" )
@Table(name = "USER")
public class MSUserTO implements Serializable {
```

Schema on Elastic:

```
 {
      "master_index" : {
        "aliases" : { },
        "mappings" : {
          "com.abc.project.entity.user.MSUserTO" : {
```

Please share the ways/concepts/logic provided by HibernateSearch/ElasticSearch to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not explicit in your question, but I assume the problem is the name of the mapping, which is different in your two applications?

- `com.abc.pt.svc.data.to.UserTO`
- `com.abc.project.entity.user.MSUserTO`

I'm afraid there is no option in Hibernate Search 5 to customize the mapping name. The reason is... Elasticsearch removed mapping names in more recent versions.
But Elasticsearch support in Hibernate Search 5 was experimental, and Hibernate Search 5 will never support Elasticsearch 6+.

So, to solve this problem, you will need to upgrade to Hibernate Search 6, which has stable support for Elasticsearch. Hibernate Search 6 is still in Beta, but it's quite stable and well tested at this point. However, its API is different from Hibernate Search 5, so migration will require some effort.

If you upgrade to Hibernate Search 6, you will be able to use Elasticsearch 5.6 if you want, because Hibernate Search 6 handles mapping names differently. Just set the [type name mapping strategy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#backend-elasticsearch-type-name) to `index-name`  and you should be able to use the same index from two different applications.

But you will also have the option to upgrade to a never version of Elasticsearch (e.g. 7.8). I would recommend this, because Elasticsearch 5.6 reached its end of life [one year ago](https://www.elastic.co/support/eol) and probably won't get any more bugfixes.

Comment: Thank You @yrodiere for the quick response, we will do a small POC on migrating to ES 6 and if it goes well will finally upgrade our systems to ES6. Will update the final outcome back here.

Comment: Though I've started on the migration part, It would be great if you could please share some resources online, where I can actually see this concept in action(code wise) as Its a bit difficult to understand this concept first hand from the documentation page, please do not take me otherwise here :) . It could be any link may be online, your own presentation links or a discourse page.

Comment: Hi @yrodiere, I've done the initial POC for this, and believe that it would be a huge task for our project to upgrade both the application at this point in time as the whole bunch of annotations are new under HS6 and we have the older annotations and API's used on lots of or entities and migrating all those would be a big effort currently, but will surely take this task up in future releases. 
Is there any other workaround of using these aliases may be from ElasticSearch side or Hibernate Search. If Yes, then it would be a quick option for us.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't use the same solution in Hibernate Search 5, because the mapping name is always the indexed class name in Hibernate Search 5 and that can't be changed. The only "quick" solution I can see would be using the same fully-qualified class name in both your applications. For example you could define the entity in a separate JAR that both your applications depend on. That's not really the spirit of microservices, but then sharing the same datastore isn't, either, so...

Comment: Regarding documentation for Hibernate Search 6: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#getting-started

Comment: We did a POC on handling this situation and below are some pointers I would like you to see and share ur view on the implementation we did.
we are now sharing the same index name between these two entities and are able to make the desired search. But now the schema has both the mappings one with UserTO and MSUserTO. And is keeping data for both the applications. Am not sure if this is a fine way, but it does solves our problem. Please share your views on PROS and CONS on this. Though I do not feel good withthis, may be my concern is not valid but still words from you will help.

Comment: As long as you're completely sure each application manipulates its own partition of the data (its own set of users) you should be fine, I suppose. If one application has to change an entitiy created by the other application, I think you'll end up with duplicates in the index, because each application will only manage its own type.  The main "con" is It's not future proof; as I said, Elasticsearch is removing support for named types and for having multiple types in the same index. That being said, when you upgrade to Hibernate Search 6, you'll just reindex everything and then you should be fine

Comment: Thanks, @yrodiere. I'll surely check on your input about the updation of entity part. And yes we will take of all these once we upgrade. But for now we should be gud.
Appreciate ur help.